# c 2248 error during private variable access

Tags: c++

I was trying to access the private variable from a class using a public function.

```
class myCls : public CFormView
{
private:
CString pvtMem;

public:
CString getPvtmem() { return pvtMem; }
}
```

I did something like this:

```
myCls *lmyCls = new myCls() ;
CString *lPvtMem = lmyCls->getPvtmem();
```

but I got error c2248
then I changed pvtMem from private to public.
But i ended up in same error.
I tried to access pvtMem directly using object since its public. 
But dint seem to work.
I did all sorts of hits like

```
myCls lmyCls;
CString lPvtMem = lmyCls.pvtMem ;
```

Compiler is not liking anything :(
well, myCls  is defined in file BatchDlg.h which i #included in 
my calling class.
I did add class reference for the last hit like class myCls in calling class.

Comment: Could you post the full compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you return "CString" but assign it to "CString *" (a pointer).

In the second example you are calling the class' operator=() method (assignment operator).  Changing "lPvtMem" will modify it's copy of the variable not the original variable.

Try:

```
CString *getPvtmem() { return &pvtMem; }

CString *lPvtMem = lMyCls.getPvtmem();
```

Now the function returns a pointer to the private member and the assignment is to a pointer to the CString class.  Now modifying lPvtMem will modify the object inside the class.